# Does useEffect with props in its dependency array rerun whenever the component renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

As seen under the [useEffect section of the React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect), props should generally be included in useEffect's dependency array:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { createConnection } from './chat.js';

function ChatRoom({ roomId }) {
  const [serverUrl, setServerUrl] = useState('https://localhost:1234');

  useEffect(() => {
    const connection = createConnection(serverUrl, roomId);
    connection.connect();
    return () => {
      connection.disconnect();
    };
  }, [serverUrl, roomId]);
  // ...
}
```

I have read somewhere that the props object passed to a react component always changes on each render. I.e. it is not the same object from one render to the next, even though the object's properties (keys and values) may be the same.

In the example above, assuming `roomId` was actually an object (and not just a number), does the useEffect not re-run on every render, even if roomId object's keys and values did not change?

Side note: As an end goal, I would like to understand the above so I can run an effect only if my destructured props object's keys and values changed.

Comment: It depends on how `roomId` is defined. If it is never re-assigned, then it won't change. But if it's re-created on each render it will be different on each render. Look into object reference equality. E.g. `{a: "A"} !== {a: "A"}`

Comment: @Phil That's not true. The `useEffect` dependency items are compared using strict equality. It doesn't do a deep object comparison.

Comment: @Cully don't mind me, I totally missed OP's point... _"assuming roomId was actually an object"_

Answer (score 1):

While your props object might change with each render, the values used in the effect hook dependencies are compared when determining when to trigger, not any objects they might be part of.

To demonstrate....

```js
const roomId = { id: 123 };
const props1 = { roomId };
const props2 = { roomId };

console.log("props equal?", props1 === props2); // false
console.log("roomId equal?", props1.roomId === props2.roomId); // true
```

So as long as the same value (or object reference) used in your hook dependencies is present in each render cycle, your effect hook will *not* re-run.

This is why the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps ESLint rule has a special mention...

> However, 'props' will change when any prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

If you cannot guarantee object equality, then I would recommend pulling out whatever identifying properties you can

```js
function ChatRoom({ roomId: { id } }) {
  const [serverUrl, setServerUrl] = useState('https://localhost:1234');

  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
  }, [serverUrl, id]);
```

Comment: The OP is asking about object comparison in useEffect deps, though. And, generally, if you don't want a prop to cause children to re-render, you use `useMemo` on object props.

Comment: @Cully sorry, not following you there. The memo hook uses the same dependency comparison as the effect hook. Also, I've edited this answer heavily since properly realising what OP was asking

Comment: I mean that the parent should use `useMemo` to settle properties passed to children when passing object props.

Comment: Thank you, both. The answer and comments fully cleared up my doubts. Maybe mention the point that the destructured object passed in as part of *props* is recreated if declared in the parent component's function body, and that `useMemo` can alleviate that issue. Just a thought, for future visitors.